# Cannot mount git dmg for installation - "no mountable file systems"

Tags: macos, installation, git, mount

I am trying to install git from the pkg and I am running into a "no mountable file systems" error when I mount the dmg downloaded from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/). When I try to mount it using the cmd `hdiutil attach -verbose /Users/computer/Downloads/git-2.15.0-intel-universal-mavericks\ \(1\).dmg`   I get the following:

```
Initializing…
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CMacBinaryEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CAppleSingleEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CEncryptedEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      900, CUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingNewWithBackingStore: CUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingNewWithBackingStore: instantiator returned 0
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CSegmentedNDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFRawEncoding
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score     1000, CUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score        0, CSparseBundleDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score        0, CSparseDiskImage
CRawDiskImage: data fork length 0x0000000001C8159A (29889946) not a multiple of 512.
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score     -100, CRawDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score        0, CDARTDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score        0, CDiskCopy42DiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CNDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  8, score     -100, CShadowedDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  9, score    -1000, CCFPlugInDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface 10, score     -100, CWrappedDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: CUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: instantiator returned 0
Verifying…
Verification completed…
Error 0 (Undefined error: 0).
expected   CRC32 $3DD6C887
Attaching…
DI_kextWaitQuiet: about to call IOServiceWaitQuiet...
DI_kextWaitQuiet: IOServiceWaitQuiet took 0.000003 seconds
2021-09-25 20:12:49.049 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] DIHelperHDID serveImage: attaching drive
{
    autodiskmount = 1;
    "hdiagent-drive-identifier" = "8752308D-57C2-4615-B644-E3115A320679";
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
}
2021-09-25 20:12:49.050 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] DIHelperHDID serveImage: connecting to myDrive 0x4C0B
2021-09-25 20:12:49.051 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] DIHelperHDID serveImage: register _readBuffer 0x10cf69000
2021-09-25 20:12:49.051 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] DIHelperHDID serveImage: activating drive port 18955
2021-09-25 20:12:49.051 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] DIHelperHDID serveImage: set cache enabled=TRUE returned SUCCESS.
2021-09-25 20:12:49.051 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] DIHelperHDID serveImage: set on IO thread=TRUE returned SUCCESS.
2021-09-25 20:12:49.051 diskimages-helper[12037:237282] -processKernelRequest: will sleep received
Volume check completed…
Mounting…
2021-09-25 20:12:49.075 diskimages-helper[12037:237280] -remountReturningDictionary: detaching because no mountable filesystems.
Attaching…
Error 112 (no mountable file systems).
Finishing…
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 112
2021-09-25 20:12:50.183 diskimages-helper[12037:237276] *** -[NSMachPort handlePortMessage:]: dropping incoming DO message because the connection is invalid
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

Any ideas? I am in a catch-22 and cannot install `brew` which would make install git easy because I need git to install `brew` in the first place. I cannot install it through xcode due to space requirements.

Comment: The .dmg might be corrupt. I'd start by re-downloading it.

Comment: Yup, corrupted. Why don't you just double-click it to mount it? That way you don't need to try get all the backslashes in the name right [especially as you appear to have two copies of it].